# How to extract against glob in tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I have set of files store into one variable and pass that variable to get duplicate and unique value in respective of variable A.

```
set A "232 234 234 234"
set a 1
set files_name "/usr/test/a_232.txt /usr/test/a1_234.txt /usr/test/a2_234.txt /usr/test/a3_234.txt"

foreach j [split $A " "] {
    incr count($j)
}
foreach key [array names count] {
    if {$count($key) == 1} {
        set file_name1 [glob -type f $file_name {$key} ]
    } else {
        set file_name2 [glob -type f $file_name {$key} ]
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm executing above code I got below error

```
no files matched glob patterns "/usr/test/a_232.txt /usr/test/a1_234.txt /usr/test/a2_234.txt /usr/test/a3_234.txt"
    while executing
"glob -type f $file_list {$key} "
```

Result should be like this

```
file_name1 : /usr/test/a_232.txt
file_name2 :/usr/test/a1_234.txt /usr/test/a2_234.txt /usr/test/a3_234.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
set A "232 234 234 234"
set files_name "/usr/test/a_232.txt /usr/test/a1_234.txt /usr/test/a2_234.txt /usr/test/a3_234.txt"

unset -nocomplain count
foreach j [split $A] {
    incr count($j)
}
foreach key [array names count] {
    if {$count($key) == 1} {
        set file_name1 [lsearch -regexp -inline $files_name $key]
    } else {
        set file_name2 [lsearch -regexp -inline -all $files_name $key]
    }
}
```

Note: `file_name2` will have as many names as there are matches for the key in the file names list, which may be more or less than there are occurrences of that key in `A`.

The `glob` command searches for file names in the file system, not in a list of files.

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)